# Form input with cursor directly after placeholder. Bootstrap 4

Tags: php, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

What is the proper way to build an input form with placeholder text in the input form with the cursor (place to start typing) directly after the placeholder text?

The placeholder text is read-only.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="functions/paypal_link.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 text-right"><img src="/images/pp.png" width="25px"> https://paypal.me/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="paypal" name="paypal" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="" required>
    </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      <center><input type="submit" value="Submit Paypal Username" class="btn btn-primary"></center>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

What I've got:

[Image - Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4UNt.png)

Here is an example of what I'd like:

[Image - Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88STi.png)

Comment: (That is not an actual _placeholder_ then to begin with.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value of your input to display your goal text `paypal.me/`. This will by default set the inputs value to `paypal.me/`. Then use some javascript to place the cursor at the end of the string within the input field. This can be acvieved using `.setSelectionRange()`  to set the start and end positions of your input field. So you can create a function then pass the value and length of your input into the function. Use `focus()` to set focus on the specified element. You can use `createTextRange()`, `moveEnd()`, `moveStart()` and `select()` together on your element with older browsers.

**EDITED:** ***(Aug 1st, 2020)***

---

Added a conditional within an event listener for `input` on your input field to check if the value of your input field at a certain substring range is set to the target string `paypal.me/` using the operator -> `!`. This keeps users from adding values to the first part or anywhere in between the set substrings range of the input field as well as checks to make certain the character slots that are in between your defined substring of your input fields value are indeed set to the desired values.

`if (!paypal.value.substring(0,10).includes('paypal.me/'))` basically says if the value of your input field for ID `paypal` does-not-include within the defined substring of the values input, `paypal.me/`, then within the conditional,
`{ paypal.value = 'paypal.me/'; }` --> set the value for the input field to equal the string `paypal.me/`.

This will only fire when the user attempts to remove the initial value that is set in the value attribute from the input field => `paypal.me/` or if they attempt to type over or into the substrings placement within the strings indices start and end range.

See code below...

```js
let paypal = document.getElementById('paypal');
let placement = paypal.length;

function setCaretPosition(el, pos) {
  // Modern browsers
  if (el.setSelectionRange) {
    el.focus();
    el.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);

    // IE8 and below
  } else if (el.createTextRange) {
    let range = el.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', pos);
    range.moveStart('character', pos);
    range.select();
  }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                              EDIT:                                      //
// add event listener to detect if your values string does not include the //
// target string within a defined set of start and end indices within your //
// string, if not we force the value to equal the string `paypal.me/`      //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
paypal.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (!paypal.value.substring(0,10).includes('paypal.me/')) {  
    paypal.value = 'paypal.me/';
  }
});

setCaretPosition(paypal, paypal.value.length);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form action="functions/paypal_link.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 text-right"><img src="/images/pp.png" width="25px"> https://paypal.me/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="paypal" name="paypal" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="paypal.me/" required>


    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <center><input type="submit" value="Submit Paypal Username" class="btn btn-primary"></center>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is it possible to make the placeholder text that is in the input field read-only, or not delete-able?

Comment: @DaveWilkins, no problem there... Just set a conditional and check the substring of the portion of the string that includes `paypal.me/` use `substring(0, 10).includes('paypal.me/')` set the conditional to check if it does not include by using the `!` operator for `does not`. This will keep the value of the first 11 characters set to your desired string and will force the input by the user to use the input beyond your desired string... Wrap it in an event listener that checks the inputs, `input` -> `paypal.addEventListener('input', function(){ // conditional here });` See my updated snippit!

Comment: If this answers your question please check the answer as accepted ;) happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use autofocus and split the username section?

```css
input[type=text], select {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
paypal.me/<input type="text" name="username" id="username" autofocus>
```

That way the input is just the username every time rather than the URL + username. If you need the full URL you can just append the username to the end of the same when saving responses however you do that. I've provided a really simple demo of how this could look.

`EDIT`

I've made a slightly more detailed one to better show how this could work.

```css
input[type=text],
select {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="wrap">
  <p>paypal.me/<input type="text" name="username" id="username" autofocus></p>
</div>
```